# Need HTTP Status (200/500/etc) Code from WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, .net

I have a .NET desktop application (not web) with a WebBrowser control.

I cannot find any information on how, or if it is even possible, to obtain the HTTP status code when a document is navigated to inside this control.  Does anyone know if this is possible or how?

The purpose is to detect codes other than 200 and perform actions accordingly within the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A web page is not made up from a single HTTP GET request.  The stackoverflow.com front page for example requires 16 requests.  Stuff like javascript code, images, page visit counters, coming from different web sites as well.  Some of it retrieve from cache instead of downloaded.

WebBrowser (aka Internet Explorer) doesn't support enumerating these individual requests.  You'd have to use the HttpWebRequest class, but that of course doesn't make a web page.

Comment: Oh dang you're right, I never thought about that.  Thanks for your insight :)